# How to get all the users in Zendesk

Tags: c#, asp.net, zendesk

I have created users using CreateOrUpdateUser() method but i was unable to fetch all the users from zendesk. I am getting null for "oListUser" also I tried to fetch user list for Organization but for that also i am getting  null.Any help would be appreciated. There is no issue with  the connection.

**Code:**

```
ZenDeskApi.ZenDeskApi oZen = new ZenDeskApi.ZenDeskApi("https://waresolution.zendesk.com", "j@se.com", "87ggh76IO");
List<User> oListUser = oZen.GetUsers();
User oUsers = new ZenDeskApi.Model.User();
oUsers.Email = "r@se.com";
oUsers.IsVerified = true;
oUsers.Name = "R r";
oUsers..........// Other properties
int a = oZen.CreateOrUpdateUser(oUsers);

List<Organization> oOrg =  oZen.GetOgranizations();
foreach (var orgItem in oOrg)
{
    int orgId = orgItem.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this zendesk api client for C#.net on Github. See the JUSTEAT [blog](http://tech.just-eat.com/2014/09/19/opensourced-the-zendeskapiclient/) for more details. You can use this client to get all users like this:

Create a client:

```
IZendeskClient client = new ZendeskClient(
    new Uri("my-zendesk-api-host-endpoint"), 
    "my-zendesk-username", 
    "my-zendesk-token"
);
```

Then you can use the Search resource to search all users:

```
var result = client.Search.Find(new ZendeskQuery<User>().WithCustomFilter("y", "x"));
```

You can download the code as a Nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZendeskApi.Client/)

Answer (score 1):

I am using ZendeskApi_v2 and I am able to get all the users using api as follows:

var userList = api.Users.GetAllUsers();

Here userList is GroupUserReponse.I doubt whether we have any method GetUsers().Atleast its not available in the version which I am using.Once you get the response you can iterate through it.

I see that this question is related to ZenDeskApi which is available at this location:
https://github.com/eneifert/ZenDeskApi.

Sorry,I have not worked on it and tried this.

Comment: 10 years old library. Is there anything more up to date or official?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got a response to this but for anyone else looking for info on the API:

Try instead of:
ZenDeskApi.ZenDeskApi oZen = new ZenDeskApi.ZenDeskApi("https://waresolution.zendesk.com", "j@se.com", "87ggh76IO");

ZenDeskApi.ZenDeskApi oZen = new ZenDeskApi("https://waresolution.zendesk.com", "j@se.com", "87ggh76IO");

Also, to get a paginated list of 100 users instead of the group response, just call:

var zendeskUsers = oZen.Users.GetAllUsers().Users;